# umbraco - xslt transformation of xml file retrieved from web site

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

i want to apply xslt transformation to a xml file , retrieved from another web server (web site).
i dont know how to do this in umbraco.
here is my xslt.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="result/job">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

and source of the xml file will be like this.

```
http://www.somesite.com/xml.aspx
```

i am totally new at umbraco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the `GetXmlDocumentByUrl()` method from the Umbraco Library.

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getxmldocumentbyurl

Your XSLT will end up looking something similar to this (dependant on the source XML structure):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="MyFeed" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlDocumentByUrl('http://www.somesite.com/xml.aspx')" />
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="$MyFeed/result/job">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="./category"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```